# Firebird.conf optimisation, slow response from both server and client

Tags: sql, database-connection, firebird, latency

I'm experiencing high latency (about 10s for each process) when using sql account software where my database is from a server.

Server spec:
Processor: Xeon E5-2630 v3
Ram: 8GB
OS: Window Server 2019
Firebird superserver 3.0
Speedtest: 100 download, 50upload
ping from client to this server, 80ms
I have 5 databases, 1-2 user each database

Client software: SQL Account [https://www.sql.com.my/](https://stackoverflow.com)

Firebird.config

```
# Configuration file for Firebird 3.0 64-bit SuperServer, optimized for best performance

ServerMode = Super
DefaultDbCachePages = 131072  # Increased page buffer for better performance
FileSystemCacheThreshold = 4M  # Increased file system cache threshold
TempBlockSize = 15M  # Further increased temp block size for better performance
TempCacheLimit = 4096M  # Further increased temp cache limit for better performance
AuthServer = Srp, Win_Sspi
AuthClient = Srp, Win_Sspi
UserManager = Legacy_UserManager, Srp
WireCrypt = Enabled
RemoteServicePort = 3050
LockMemSize = 99999999
LockHashSlots = 30011

DatabaseAccess = Full
RemoteAccess = true
ExternalFileAccess = None
UdfAccess = Restrict UDF
DatabaseGrowthIncrement = 256M  # Increased database growth increment
FileSystemCacheSize = 600M  # Increased file system cache size
TcpRemoteBufferSize = 60480k  # Increased TCP remote buffer size
TcpNoNagle = 1 
CpuAffinityMask = 0xFF
ProcessPriorityLevel = -15  # Further decreased process priority level for higher priority
DummyPacketInterval = 500  # Set a non-zero dummy packet interval for better TCP keep-alive

# Dedicated Temporary Directories for Each Database
main.fdb = C:\Databases\main.fdb
{
    TempDirectories = C:\Temp\main
}

second.fdb = C:\Databases\second.fdb
{
    TempDirectories = C:\Temp\second
}

third.fdb = C:\Databases\third.fdb
{
    TempDirectories = C:\Temp\third
}

employee.fdb = $(dir_sampleDb)/employee.fdb
employee = $(dir_sampleDb)/employee.fdb
{
    TempDirectories = C:\Temp\employee
}
```

Database.config

```
# Configuration file for Firebird databases, optimized by IBSurgeon, released 23 March 2020
# It is optimized for 8-12Gb RAM. Apply firebird_30_superserver_64bit_ram8gb.conf with this configuration!

## In this example, we assume you have 1 big and loaded database main.fdb, 
## and 2 less loaded second.fdb and third.fdb 

## Rename aliases and change paths according to your databases' names

## The recommended total page buffers size is 25-30% for all databases!
## If you have more databases on the same server, increase RAM, or reduce page buffers even more,
## or consider using SuperClassic/Classic (use appropriate conf files)
## If you have only 1 database, you may increase DefaultDbCachePages up to 185K.

########## Any questions? Contact us: support@ib-aid.com

main.fdb=C:\Databases\main.fdb
{
    DefaultDbCachePages = 300K  # 1Gb of RAM for page buffers for 8K pagesize, 2Gb for 16k pagesize 
}

second.fdb=C:\Databases\second.fdb
{
    DefaultDbCachePages = 30K # 240Mb of RAM for page buffers for 8k pagesize, 480Mb for 16k pagesize
}

third.fdb=C:\Databases\third.fdb
{
    DefaultDbCachePages = 30K # 240Mb of RAM for page buffers for 8k pagesize, 480Mb for 16k pagesize
}

### from the original databases.conf

employee.fdb = $(dir_sampleDb)/employee.fdb
employee = $(dir_sampleDb)/employee.fdb

# Master security database specific setup.
# Do not remove it until you understand well what you are doing!
security.db = $(dir_secDb)/security3.fdb
{
    RemoteAccess = false
    DefaultDbCachePages = 20k  # Increased buffer size for the security database
}
```

Does anyone know how to further optimise the configuration and reduce the latency? I can see that server and client not utilising alot of resources and bandwidth.Thanks

Comment: For such configuration you should have at least 32 GB RAM. Perhaps you missed zero in server specs?.. Do you monitor server resource consumption at all?

Comment: @user13964273 , may i know how to monitor and what should i do next?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor You should learn some basics about Windows administration. What is RAM, CPU, HDD and how they are used.

Comment: `TcpRemoteBufferSize = 60480k` this values cannot be higher than 32767, and you're setting it nearly 1900 times higher. I'm not sure what it does if you set an invalid value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It'll be silently assigned to max.